# setting auto decimals at input box in jquery not working

Tags: jquery, decimal

Hi everyone i am new in jquery i created some input box and want when some one enters some value or the input get value for database it will automatically add decimal upto 2 i applied this code but it is not working kindly help me

```js
         ?>
         <script type="text/javascript">
         function setTwoNumberDecimal(event) {
        this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
          }
         </script>
         <?
```

```html
  print '<tr><td>';
 print fieldLabel('Others Deductions','other_deduction',1).'</td><td>';
 print '<input  class="sub"  onchange="setTwoNumberDecimal(this)" name="other_deduction" id="other_deduction" size="10" value="'.GETPOST("other_deduction").'">';
 print '</td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following code snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#text1").bind('change',function(){
    var value=$(this).val();
    $(this).val(parseFloat(value).toFixed(2));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1" />
```

Hope this helps

Few suggestions

1. Never mix your markup with javascript. Try binding your events change/click at javascript end
2. In your setvalue method code, your passing event as parameter and trying to access this.value, this here would refer to window object

Hope this helps

Comment: still it is not working plus one thing more that my data in input box are also coming from database using json and jquery

Comment: my code worked i just put the function in the old fjquery body and it worked sorry it was a silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

> Everthing is okay, just use event inside function instead of this.

**Testting purpose pure html code and your code:**

```js
  function setTwoNumberDecimal(event) {
    event.value = parseFloat(event.value).toFixed(2);
  }
```

```html
<input type="text  class="sub"  onchange="setTwoNumberDecimal(this)" name="other_deduction" id="other_deduction" size="10" value="">
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setTwoNumberDecimal(event) {
    event.value = parseFloat(event.value).toFixed(2);
  }
  </script>
```

```html
<?php    print '<tr><td>';
 print fieldLabel('Others Deductions','other_deduction',1).'</td><td>';
 print '<input  class="sub"  onchange="setTwoNumberDecimal(this)" name="other_deduction" id="other_deduction" size="10" value="'.GETPOST("other_deduction").'">';
 print '</td></tr>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are passing an object to your javascript function (which is correct) but are not using it like you should.

The code should look like this:

```js
      function setTwoNumberDecimal(obj) {
        obj.value = parseFloat(obj.value).toFixed(2);
          }
```

```html
  <tr>
  <td>Others Deductions</td>
  <td>
<input type="text" class="sub" onchange="setTwoNumberDecimal(this)" name="other_deduction" id="other_deduction" size="10" value="" />
  </td>
</tr>
```